# Why do Solidity's array slices do not have any members in their arrays?

Tags: solidity, arrays

I am reading about Array slices in the Solidity documentation [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.18/types.html#array-slices). According to the docs, Array slices do not have any members. Can anyone shed light on why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

the lack of members in array slices is due to the fact that they are simply a view into an array and do not have their own storage. This design choice makes array slices more memory-efficient but also limits their functionality.